# NumberFormatter: is currency incompatible with positivePrefix?

Tags: swift, currency, numberformatter

I stumbled on an issue related to `NumberFormatter`. When I set the `positivePrefix` to the `plusSign`, the currency symbol is no longer there.

Is that a bug or did I miss something?

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
formatter.currencyCode = "EUR"
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.positivePrefix = formatter.plusSign // Remove that to get €25 (depends on your locale)
let price = 25.0
let s = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: price))

print("Price: \(s)"). // "Price: +25"
```

Comment: Not related to your question but you don't need to create a `NSNumber` object. You can use `Formatter`'s method `string(for: Any)` method and pass your `Double` object `formatter.string(for: price)`

Comment: Why would you need to add a plus sign to your price string? There would never be a negative price anyways.

Comment: I think you're expected to manually glue `formatter.currencySymbol` back in whatever position makes sense for your custom prefix, e.g. `formatter.positivePrefix = "+" + formatter.currencySymbol`

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica this won't work if OP is trying to add the currency symbol before or after depending on the locale

Comment: @LeoDabus Oh yeah, good point

Comment: There are lots of cases where someone might have a negative currency value, such as in financial investing with relative decreases in the price of a stock.

Answer (score 3):

When the currency sign precedes the numeric value (that depends on the locale) then `positivePrefix` contains the currency sign. So changing it to `formatter.plusSign` just clears the currency sign from the result string.

This is how I solved the issue:

```
formatter.positivePrefix = formatter.negativePrefix.replacingOccurrences(of: formatter.minusSign, with: formatter.plusSign)
```

Comment: a tricky way, but universal. Thank you!